# How to set current page with Yii's CActiveDataProvider?

Tags: yii, pagination, cactivedataprovider

I've created this CActiveDataProvider:

```
  $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post',array(
    'criteria'=>array(
      'condition'=>$condition,
      'params'=>$params,
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
      'pageSize'=>2,
    ),
  ));
```

but ... How can I define current page and load records 3,4 instead of 1,2?
How can I get a precise page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the zero-based [`currentPage`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#currentPage-detail) attribute of the `pagination`

```
...
'pagination'=>array(
  'pageSize'=>2,
  'currentPage'=>1,
),
...
```